# VLC can't play MP4 files to Living Room TV through Chromecast

Tags: 20.04, vlc, mp4, chromecast

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and VLC 3.0.9.2. I have a Chromecast plugged in one of my TV's HDMI ports. Using VLC's Renderer function, I can play MKV or AVI files on my TV (identified as "Living Room TV"), but I doesn't work for MP4 files: when I try, I get a black screen with the file's name shown for a few seconds, then nothing happens. Help!

Comment: It's not the container (MP4, MKV, etc.) that matters, it's the codecs within: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a converter like [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), sometimes there are presets for media streaming devices and such.

Answer (score 0):

MP4 is just the container, but you have have transcode this movie. You could try https://github.com/Reggino/chromecaster for realtime transcoding

(disclaimer, author here)